# mod_cloudflare on elastic beanstalk

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, httpd.conf, cloudflare

I tried to install it by supplying a config file like this:

```
packages:
  rpm:
    mod_cloudflare: https://www.cloudflare.com/static/misc/mod_cloudflare/centos/mod_cloudflare-el6-x86_64.latest.rpm

files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/cloudflare.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      CloudFlareRemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
      CloudFlareRemoteIPTrustedProxy 10.0.0.0/8
```

but it ends up not installing it correctly:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/cloudflare.conf:
Invalid command 'CloudFlareRemoteIPHeader', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I found that there is no load_module on the cloudflare.so so after adding the load module manually into the cloudflare.conf I'm getting this:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 353 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/cloudflare.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_cloudflare.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_cloudflare.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_rerror
```

I couldn't find a solution yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed it:

```
packages:
  yum:
      glibc.i686: []
      libtool: []
      httpd24-devel: [] // <--!

commands:
  00-cloudflare: 
    command: wget https://www.cloudflare.com/static/misc/mod_cloudflare/mod_cloudflare.c
    cwd: /tmp
  01-cloudflare: 
    command: apxs -a -i -c mod_cloudflare.c
    cwd: /tmp

files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/cloudflare.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      CloudFlareRemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
      CloudFlareRemoteIPTrustedProxy 10.0.0.0/8
```